# finding binary image Intersections using morphological operators in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i need to use morphological operators dilation, erosion and etc' to find intersections on a binart image.
got any idea?
thanks.

Comment: The definition of your problem is a little vague, but I think what you're trying to do may be similar to what was addressed in this other question: [How to find the most dense regions in an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001475/how-to-find-the-most-dense-regions-in-an-image). At the very least it may give you some new ideas. ;)

Answer (score 0):

can you specify what you mean by intersections.  Do you have lines that intersect or regions that touch or something else?  regionprops is an excellent place to start with this stuff in matlab when you know what you are after

Comment: i have lines that touch, sometimes they can be a bit blured so pre handling of the image should be made